# Receive POST data in non-UTF-8 encoding (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, character-encoding

my ASP.NET MVC Application is UTF-8, but I receive POST request in Encoding.Default from third-party app out of my control.

What is sanest and simplest way to change **request** encoding for **only one action of one controller**? (Rest of my application should remain UTF-8).

```
public class Message
{
 public int id { get; set; }
 public string phone { get; set; }
 public string mes { get; set; }
 public string to { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Receive(Message msg)
{
        AddIncomingMessage(msg);
        return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: 3.5 years later and still no real answer, not even remote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do Action based request encoding in ASP.NET MVC with web.config location tag setting.


Sample web.config:

```
<configuration>
...
<location path="path/to/your/actionmethod">
    <system.web>
        <globalization requestEncoding="ISO-8859-1" responseEncoding="ISO-8859-1" />
    </system.web>
</location>
...
</configuration>
```

http://www.siimviikman.com/2012/06/12/action-based-request-encoding-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score -2):

I was struggling with the same problem, so after some research I came up with this solution:

1. Create a custom Action Filter Attribute:

   ```
   public class CharsetAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
       private readonly string _charset = null;

       public CharsetAttribute() : this("UTF-8")
       {}
       public CharsetAttribute(string charset)
       {
           _charset = charset;
       }

       public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {
           filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] += string.Concat(";charset=", _charset);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Put that on your action specifying the desired encoding; in my case:

   ```
   [CharsetAttribute("ISO-8859-1")]
   public ActionResult MyAction(ThirdPartyViewModel model)
   { (...) }
   ```

Comment: Diego, I ask about encoding of Request, not response! Set encoding of Response is fairly simple :)